# What kind of optimizations AVM2 supports?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-optimization, avm2

I wonder, what kind of optimizations AVM2 (ActionScript 3 VM) support? I know it uses JIT but does it support Dead Code Elimination, constant folding, inlining, etc.

Also it's very interesting to me that ActionScript compiler also do some optimizations. AFAIK C# compiler does very small set of optimizations (only required for language support), JIT  does all the work. And it works very fast.

Thanks.

**Thanks to MPD. AVM2 supports:**

- **Constant Folding**
- **Copy & Constant Propagation**
- **Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE)**
- **Dead Code Elimination (DCE)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these slides: [ActionScript 3.0 and AVM2: Performance Tuning](http://labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/as3-performance/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Presentation is a little bit old (2006 year) but it has info that I was looking for.  AVM2 supports: Constant Folding, Copy & Constant Propagation, Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE), Dead Code Elimination (DCE)

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you aren't aware, Grossman was the original developer of Actionscript.  I think that paper coincides with the release of AS3 and the AVM2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Flash/Flex compiler do most of this optimizations, but you can achieve this results with 3rd party softwares, like [secureSWF](http://www.kindisoft.com/) (commercial).

Maybe you can find another tool that is free or Open Source that does this too.